# Wifi is unavailable on Kali OS

Tags: network-adapter, kali-linux, wifi-configuration

The wifi is "unavailable". No networks are showing in the wifi settings. I have tried fixing through the command line with ifconfig, iwconfig and everything else. As far as I know my router is connected to my laptop but I have no internet. It isn't a router issue as all my other devices have internet access. I am online through an ethernet connection but I can't get any wifi signals in an apartment building full of them. Also I was able to get signals and connect when I originally installed kali. Below is a image of a new message I get on startup. But when I prompt firmware updates on the command line it says everything is up to date and installed. Looking for help to make sense of this.

```
/dev/sda2: clean, 359036/30236672 files, 4305622/120945664 blocks
[    11.239646] platform regulatory.0: firmware: failed to load regulatory.db
[    11.239640] firmware_class: See https://wiki.debian.org/firmware for information about missin firmware
```

Comment: So if you could get WiFi signal when you first installed Kali, what have you changed?

Answer (score 0):

I restarted the networkmanager and wpa_supplicant which turned on wifi signals again. Since I messed around with the network manager before it was the wpa_supplicant that came through. Not sure why yet but issue fixed.